# Uncaught (in promise) API <api_name> does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I'm trying to add existing backend to a new react frontend. Every time I call the API from react i get,
Uncaught (in promise) API api3ceaf69c does not exist

Client side code

```
function getData() {
  const apiName = "api3ceaf69c"; 
  const path = "/users"; 
  const myInit = {
    
    headers: {}, 
  };
  return API.get(apiName, path, myInit);
}

(async function () {
  const response = await getData();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
})();
```

index.js

```
import { Amplify, API } from "aws-amplify";
import awsExports from "./aws-exports";
Amplify.configure(awsExports);
API.configure(awsExports);
```

aws-exports.json

```
{
    "aws_cloud_logic_custom": [
            {
                "name": "api3ceaf69c",
                "endpoint": "https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev",
                "region": "ap-south-1"
            }
        ]
}
```

"aws-amplify": "^4.3.27"

Error
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8bZ1.png)

I went through multiple answers around the same issue but none of them are working for me.

Interestingly this exact same code was working a few days back until I had to rebuild my backend due to some changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem finally! Issue was at the place where I'm calling `Amplify.configure(aws_exports)`.
For some reason aws exports was not getting initialized in index.js file so I moved it closer to where I am actually calling the api, i.e. getData() function. It started working post that.

Answer (score 1):

I thought client code used [aws-exports.js](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/reference/files/#aws-exportsjs) to decide if the API exists. Looks like you may have checked it already. Does the xxxxxxx API from your exports file show up in the API Gateway in AWS Console? Can you invoke it from the console?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).